# inheritance in C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a beginner in C++ QT. I'd like to know

**Q1.** What is the effect when I pass the "`parent`" parameter into the parent class => `QDialog(parent)`? **Q2**.What does this mean `ui(new Ui::MyDialog)`?

This is .cpp code.

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

In .h code.

```
namespace Ui {
    class MyDialog;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your user-interface, you have at least 2 choices: hard-code or use `Qt Designer` which create `XML` code which describes your window. Next `uic` (user interface compiler) translate this `XML` code into real valid `C++/Qt` code and save it inside `ui_name.h` and you need include this code to your class. It is exactly what code in your question does. It declare your class inside `Ui` namespace and allocate memory for this class (in constructor). Next you call `setupUi(this);`. This method contains all main code, such as allocating memory for widgets, handling layouts, establish connections, etc.

About parent: it is part of `Qt` object-tree system which simplifies memory handling in `Qt`. As you know `C++` is not a garbage-collected language and you need to delete memory manually. But `Qt` offers you new solution where parent destroys all children, so it is simpler way. This parent in your code means that `MyDialog` is a children of `QDialog`.

[More information.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html)